# How to connect a MySQL database on a remote machine

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

My apologize, this question may seem obvious...but I'm not an expert in system administration.

I have a Windows server (on my Intranet) running Apache 2.2 and MySQL 5.1. The server has PHPMyAdmin  installed.

When I open http://servername/phpmyadmin I can see, edit the SQL database (note that I'm not asked for any login/password but I see in PHPMyAdmin that I'm logged as root@localhost).

Now, when I try to open the database from a tool installed on y machine (HeidiSQL), I can't get the connection right.

When I specify no user name, it reports `Access denied for 'ODBC'@'my local machine name'`. I tried to specify `root@servername`, `root@%`....but 'my local machine name' always gets appended to the name I enter and connexion is refused.

How can I get this HeidiSQL tool be able to connect the database? What user name should I specifiy?

Comment: Open phpmyadmin and add permissions for your user from your local machine name.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: Nice, it worked. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add additional privileges for access from your machine to MySQL to the following:

1. Open phpMyAdmin
2. Go to the `User accounts` tab
3. Find the user you want to use, click on `Edit privileges`
4. Go to `Login Information`
5. Enter the hostname of your local machine into the `Host name` field.
   <sub>make sure the dropdown next to it is set to `Use text field:`</sub>
6. Make sure `Create a new user account with the same privileges and keep the old one` is selected and click on `Go`

Of course, you can also create a completely new user, use a different password, whatever you want. MySQL considers credentials from different machines as different users.